# I had trouble setting the ATR value as the stoploss in mql4

Tags: mql4, metatrader4, expert-advisor

When I take a test, error messages occur for the stoploss and the take profit, and the trade is not opened.
Please look at the code, where I am doing wrong?

```
input double atrXsl = 1.5;
input double atrXtp = 1.5;

void sell()
  {
   double atr = iATR(_Symbol, _Period, 14, 1);
   double sl = Bid + ((atr * atrXsl) / Point);
   double tp = Bid - ((atr * atrXtp) / Point);
   
   OrderSend(_Symbol,OP_SELL,0.01,Bid,3,sl,tp,"Sell Submited",593,0,clrRed);
  }
```